# Compile JAR with core dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that has 2 applications (similar to a server and client) that both have the same core which contains methods to access a database and a configuration file. I need to be able to package both applications with minimal effort. It would also be helpful to work with all 'modules' in the same window of my IDE (I am using IntelliJ). Is a multi-module Maven project a good fit for this and if so how would you be able to package each module separately.

Hopefully this makes it more clear of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: What is your packaging target for the application? is it WAR/JAR/EAR? please give entire details.

Comment: @CuriousMind I am attempting to package it as a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Make core a separate module and add it as a dependency in both your projects. You would get 3 jars - Core.jar, App1.jar and App2.jar. And both App1.jar as well as App2.jar would have core.jar as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification you have given in the post and the comment, I will suggest you a following approach

Create 4 different project with below structure

```
MyProjectParent
--Core
--App1
--App2
```

**Grouping dependencies**

Declare `MyProjectParent` as a parent POM and rest of the projects as child modules. Use `MyProjectParent` to declare the dependencies across the child project i.e. core, app1 and app2. Hence it will reduce the pain in future to change any version numbers or dependencies across projects. In child modules you will just need references to the groupID, artifactID. You can find more information about creating modules [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html) and [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects).

**Packaging Type**

For all  the child modules use JAR as a packaging type.

**Assembly definition**

Use Maven `assembly` feature to create distributable zip (or any other format you desire) to package App1 and App2 as a whole unit. You can even package shell/batch script to enable execution of the respective project. You can find more information about creating assembly [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).